# c# how correctly edit objects with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-columns

I've been struggling with DataGrid.

I need to read data from SQL and populate them to table, with possibility to edit them (it's not required to upload changes back to DB). Then based on the table, I will generate a report.

I never worked with DataGrid before and I'm also new to WPF concepts, but here are two approaches I tried.

**First One:** `dataGridItems.ItemsSource = previewItems;` where `previewItems` is list of `Item` objects.

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public Item(string itemName, string itemCode, decimal itemPrice = 0)
    {
        this.ItemName = itemName;
        this.ItemCode = itemCode;
        this.ItemPrice = itemPrice;
    }
}
```

I can read/write data - as I would like to. Problem with this solution I have is about column size, which is dynamically resized based on data which are currently visible.

**Second One** : Binding in XAML.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGridItems" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="691,10,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="628" Width="791" MinWidth="260" MouseDoubleClick="dataGridItems_MouseDoubleClick">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Kód" MinWidth="60" Width="10*" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemCode}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Název výkonu" MinWidth="200" Width="90*" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Then in cycle, I was adding items

`DataGridCustomer.Items.Add(customer);`

This worked for me, untill I found that application is crashing whenever I double click on `DataGrid` cell.Even if I set `IsReadOnly="True"`, which is somethink I do no underestand.

I spent hours to find a sollution - found some, but either I did not underestand or they were not working.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> [...] which is dynamically resized based on data which are currently visible

You can style the column as you like. Assuming *dt* is your *DataGrid*, handle the *AutoGeneratingColumn* event:

```
      dt.AutoGeneratingColumn += Dt_AutoGeneratingColumn;
 //....
 private void Dt_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
 {
     DataGridColumn col = e.Column;
     // you can set the maximum width of the column:
     col.MaxWidth = 200.0;
     // or you can define a element style, for text wrapping, etc.
     col.CellStyle = (Style)FindResource("cellStyle");
  }
```

in which the Style is declared in *App.xaml*. Something like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="cellStle">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can I define colums size for specific column? Now it sets all comlumns in datagrid.

Comment: Check the _e.Column.Header_ or _e.Column.DisplayIndex_ or any other information, and if you don't want to change anything, just use return.